What does Markandeya Puranam say about Shraddha karma? What rules are to be followed?
What are the rules prescribed to be followed as per Markandeya Puranam for Shraddha karma?

You can refer the book of Gita press antay karm shraddha prakash it contains the rules that must be followed

@ShriHarivansh that doesn't answer my question does it?

That's why I didn't answer and only did comment so that if you are in search of shraddh rules then it is compilation of all the rules

@ShriHarivansh never mind my bad

Why only from the Markandeya Purana? any specific reason? https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/essay/markandeya-purana-study/d/doc1121536.html

@Harihara thanks but as far as I am aware non veg shouldn't be avoided in shraddham performed in Kali Yugam. Do you know any scripture talking about it?

The Markandeya Purana is Tamasic as per the Garuda Purana. So, the rites as per the Sattvic Puranas would take precedence. Hence, non-veg is to be avoided.

@Harihara I know non veg should be avoided. But I want a source on that. As you are saying Sattwik Puranas says to avoid it it would be good if you could quote any one if possible.

@Harihara I am asking for prohibition of meat in shraddhas explicitly in kaliyugam. Any idea about that?

The verse applies to any yuga. The Bhagavatam is not just for Kali Yuga ans was written at the onset of Kali Yuga anyways. Offering meat is never pleasing to the Lord. I'm not aware of such a verse.
